# BehaviorSubject not returning the latest value in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am building a website in `angular` (latest version) but my problem is the `BehaviorSubject` from `RxJS` is not working

**service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class ServicesService  {     
    constructor() { 
        this.getCartList() 
    }   productObj  
    private productObj = new BehaviorSubject({'total':0,'products':[]})  

    get getTheNo(){
        return localStorage.getItem('cartNo') ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem('cartNo')) : 0
    }
    get getCartItemCount() {
        return this.cartItemCount;
    }   
    get getCartItemPop() {
        return this.productObj;
    }           
    getCartList(){
        .......
        ......
        this.productObj.value.products.push({'id':cookarfg[0],'name':cookarfg[2],'amount':cookarfg[2],'price':cookarfg[3],'pics':cookarfg[4]})
        this.productObj.value.total=cookarfg[3]
        this.productObj.next(this.productObj.value);
    }       
}
```

here is the code for the header.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ServicesService } from '../../services/services.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    productObj: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    constructor(
        private service: ServicesService,
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.productObj = this.service.getCartItemPop;
        console.log('console-> ',this.service.getCartItemPop)
    }
}
```

what I want is that whenever the page loads, it will update the `productObj` to the latest values instead of `{'total':0,'products':[]}`, but it's not working. I tried everything but it's still not working, pls I need your help, am still new to `angular`, Thanks

Comment: Fist of all you are doing weird stuff in `getCartList()`, you are manipulating `value` of the BehaviorSubject, that's not how to do it. The docs have an example of how to implement this pattern, it should help you: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Another thing is that you seem to have 2 projectObj defined (!?) 
`productObj  
    private productObj`

Answer (score 1):

I see there are some errors in your program and fixing below.

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class ServicesService {
  constructor() {
    this.getCartList();
  }

  cartItemCount;
  productObj = new BehaviorSubject({'total': 0, 'products': []});

  get getTheNo() {
    return localStorage.getItem('cartNo') ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem('cartNo'), 0) : 0;
  }

  get getCartItemCount() {
    return this.cartItemCount;
  }

  get getCartItemPop() {
    return this.productObj;
  }

  getCartList() {

    // As productObj is a BehaviorSubject and not an arror or ordinary object, you cannot push value directly
    /*this.productObj.value.products.push({
      'id': cookarfg[0],
      'name': cookarfg[2],
      'amount': cookarfg[2],
      'price': cookarfg[3],
      'pics': cookarfg[4]
    });
    this.productObj.value.total = cookarfg[3];*/
    this.productObj.next({value: 'push the value here' }); // productObj is BehaviorSubject, you need to subscribe it to get its value
  }
}
```

Then your header component will subscribe the BehavourSubject and extract the value out of it like below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from '../../services/services.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  productObj: any;
  constructor(
    private service: ServicesService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.productObj.subscribe((value => {
      console.log('console-> ', value);
      this.productObj = value;
    }));

  }
}
```

You were directly changing value of `BehaviorSubject` which might be the problem. And `productObj` is `BehaviorSubject`, you need to subscribe it to get its value.

Comment: pls how am i going to do it, am new to angular and BehaviorSubject

Comment: I edited and added the section how to subscribe and get the value. try it now. make adjustment if required

Comment: Your answer seems good, but you need to have a set method where you will set the values to BS and getCartList method will return the BS and then you will subscribe it in component.